# meteor: How to use Font Awesome with Handlebars?

Tags: meteor, handlebars.js, font-awesome

First off, I placed this in the HEAD section of my template:

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

I decided I wanted to use the music symbol and inserted it like so:

```
<div id="close_player">&#xf001;</div>` where the symbol is given by ` fa-music (&#xf001;)
```

However, when my page loads for some reason I see only `fi` instead of the Font Awesome symbol I'm supposed to be seeing. The source displays the following:

```
<div id="close_player"></div>
```

What is going on, and how do I resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Cuberto suggested add the package using mrt,
Then you can do something like this, consider you have iron router and you got 2 icons in every page at your app, and they change according to the route:

```
<template name='myHomeTemplate'>
<i class={{iconOne}}></i>
<i class={{iconTwo}}></i>
</template>
```

Then in  your router logic you can do

```
this.route('home', {
path: '/',
template: 'myHomeTemplate',
layoutTemplate: 'layout',
yieldTemplates: {
  'myAsideTemplate': {to: 'aside'},
  'myFooter': {to: 'footer'}
},

data: {
  iconOne: 'fa fa-music',
  iconTwo:'fa fa-camera'
}
});
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, don't put CSS links in your head. Just add the meteorite package - `mrt add font-awesome`. This will automatically add the CSS link when you run the app, and it will concatenate and minify it with all your other CSS in deployment. Then, just use the icons the font awesome way:

```
<i class="fa fa-music"></i>
```